# Can I use calculation group to get multiple cost columns?

Tags: powerbi, dax

My dataset contains 5 fields cost, month, group, name, type. The requirement is to show cost of last 6 months in a table visual for the specific- group, name, type. I'm currently using a matrix but the requirement is to show fields group, name, and type as columns.

The option I tried was creating 6 measures to calculate the cost of last 6 months (1 per month). I'm wondering if there is a better way to handle this. Calculation group uses a selected measure, not sure if it works for this use case.

Comment: Do you not have a Calendar table? Something here is missing. Can you post some sample data?